# Python DICOM--pixel dimension

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom, nifti

I beginner in DICOM file, how to find pixel dimension or dim in these files? As we find these elements in the nifti files!

[image]

Comment: It generally depends on the modality. For many modalities (like MR and CT) you will find the x/y dimension in the tag `PixelSpacing`. For the the z dimension, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389506/how-to-calculate-a-voxel-size), but it also depends on the modality.

Answer (score 3):

With the `pydicom` library you can get the pixel spacing and pixel data dimensions in the following way:

```py
import pydicom

ds = pydicom.dcmread("/path/to/dcm_file.dcm")

# The size of each pixel
pixel_spacing = ds.PixelSpacing

# The number of pixels in each frame
rows = ds.Rows
columns = ds.Columns

# The number of frames, if there's more than 1
nr_frames = getattr(ds, "NumberOfFrames", 1)
```